# Finding Mode based of conditional criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, conditional-statements, match, mode

I would like to be able to find the most common value given a certain criteria in an adjacent column. For example:

```
>**ROW A**  -----   **ROW B**  
>Blue ---------- Jason  
>Blue ---------- Jason  
>Blue ---------- Charles   
>Red ---------- Alfred  
>Red ---------- Alfred  
>Red ---------- Barry  
>Green --------- Barry
```

I would like a formula that could look like the following

> > > > `if(X=Row_A_Value,Mode of X)`

For instance if "BLUE" then the output would be "JASON". If "RED" the output would be "ALFRED"

I've tried using Index(Mode(Match)) without any luck...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the prettiest formula, but this array formula works: (line break added for readability)

```
= INDEX(B1:B7,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIFS(A1:A7,"Blue",B1:B7,B1:B7)),
  COUNTIFS(A1:A7,"Blue",B1:B7,B1:B7),0))
```

There probably is a more efficient way but this is just the first one I could think of.

Obviously, just replace the two instances of `"Blue"` in the formula above with `"Red"` in order to search for red instead.

Note this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing this formula rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

See below, working example.

[image]

Comment: Hoo boy it is ugly but it also works perfect for my purposes! Thanks!

Comment: Okay, but this formula makes the excel sheet to hang, what to do about it?

Comment: @MujeeburRahman This formula likely only works for small ranges, it might hang for larger ranges. You should post a new question, reference this page, and say that you want to accomplish the same thing but with a different method since this doesn't work for large ranges.