# Excel - How to Efficiently Return Index of Max Value

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, max

Is there a way to return the *index* of the (first) `MAX` value of an array in Excel, *without* using the array in the formula twice?

I.e., not like this:

```
= MATCH(MAX(<array>),<array>,0)
```

If `<array>` is a long formula in itself, then the formula is seemingly twice as long (and inefficient) as it should be. I am just trying to avoid this, if possible.

Comment: It depends on your data and layout, but typically when you want to improve efficiency you'll need to use a helper column so that you get your results and then just need to reference those (instead of having to recalc your results all the time).  Again, without knowing your data layout it's hard to give more specific suggestions.

Comment: Understood that helper cells will help shorten formulas, but I don't really even see how helper cells could help with efficiency in this case. For example you could store in cell `A1`: `= MAX(<array>)` and then use `= MATCH(A1,<array>,0)`, but as I already commented in the answer below, this more masks the issue, since `<array>` still needs to be calculated twice, separately.

Comment: I meant more that your helper column would contain the <array> so that it is only calculated once. And then you can run operations against the helper column.  If possible, can you provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: @tigeravatar I just answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629972/finding-mode-based-of-conditional-criteria/48630540#48630540), which made me think of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use the MAX value quite often in the file, you can create a named range for it and put the MAX formula in the value of the named range.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. You are correct that `MAX(<array>)` could be stored in another cell but ultimately `<array>` still needs to be calculated again separately. Your answer masks the problem rather than solves it.