# Finding Mode based on conditional criteria

Tags: excel, mode

With reference to the question in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629972/finding-mode-based-of-conditional-criteria/48630540?noredirect=1#comment116166307_48630540), the solutions provided were for small cell ranges. If it is applied on a sheet with large ranges, then the sheet gets hanged. Is there any method for working a similar method for large excel ranges?

Comment: how large are we talking?

Answer (score 0):

The original Countifs formula would look like this for 10K cells:

```
=INDEX(B1:B10000,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIFS(A1:A10000,"Blue",B1:B10000,B1:B10000)),
  COUNTIFS(A1:A10000,"Blue",B1:B10000,B1:B10000),0))
```

A modified formula using Match is much faster than the original countifs formula:

```
=INDEX(B1:B10000,MODE(IF(A1:A10000="Blue",MATCH(B1:B10000,B1:B10000,0))))
```

Original formula 2.5 seconds, Match formula 0.15 seconds using [this timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff700515(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

With Microsoft 365, you can filter for just the Blue rows and it is a lot faster again.

This version of the formula runs in .003 seconds:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(B1:B10000,A1:A10000="Blue"),MODE(MATCH(FILTER(B1:B10000,A1:A10000="Blue"),FILTER(B1:B10000,A1:A10000="Blue"),0)))
```

and this one in 0.002 seconds

```
=LET(x,FILTER(B1:B10000,A1:A10000="Blue"),INDEX(x,MODE(MATCH(x,x,0))))
```

Timings carried out on Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10400 CPU @ 2.90GHz, 2904 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s) using Microsoft 365 and Windows 10.

The test data used seven different colours and seven different names, generated with

```
=INDEX(G$1:G$7,RANDBETWEEN(1,7))
```

and

```
=INDEX(H$1:H$7,RANDBETWEEN(1,7))
```

[image]

Since the response is O(N^2), it seems reasonable that reducing the search space by a factor of 7 should reduce the time by a factor of about 50.